# Best way to display data fromm an API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering what is the best way to display data from a rest API.

Actually what I do:

- Call fetch function from `componentDidMount()`;
- `setState` to store my response
- Check with ternary when `render()` if the value is set or not

It look like this :

*(`getcall()` is a fetch function) :*

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const response= await getCall(
        `event?ref=23876186`, // this is just to illustrate
      );
    this.setState({ payload: response})
}
```

Then in `render()` I do some :

```
 {this.state.payload ? (
  <h1>{this.state.payload.event.name}</h1>) : ( <h1></h1>)}
```

I though about calling my `fetch` function from the `constructor`, but it's weird to call an `async` function in a `constructor`, you loose the `aync` purpose.

I imagine some case like for an `input` :

```
  <Input 
     type="text" 
     name="name" 
     id="name" 
     **value={this.state.event.name}**
     placeholder="Name..." 
     onChange={this.handleName}
     required
   />
```

If I want to set a value for it, like `this.state.event.name`, if I have 10 fields, I will have 10*2 times this kind of code because for each one I wrote a ternary.

So what is the best way to display data from an API call?

Comment: Just use if else if data is not ready then show loading else inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a lot of ternaries where you check if `payload` is set, you can return `null` early from the `render` method if it is not set yet.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    payload: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await getCall("/event?ref=23876186");
    this.setState({ payload: response });
  }

  render() {
    const { payload } = this.state;

    if (payload === null) {
      return null;
    }
    return <div>{/* ... */}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you I did It and it display a little "Loading..."  before redering